# preg_match adds an unwanted whitespace

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, eol

Let's write a file with a Windows editor (thus, generating different endline char than Unix probably):

```
TITLE:Hello
URL:hello.html
AUTHOR:Bob
```

Then

```
content = file_get_contents($page);
preg_match("/^URL:(.*)$/m", $content, $matches);      

echo $matches[1] . '#test';
```

returns

```
hello.html 
#test
```

instead of

```
hello.html#test
```

I can solve the problem by doing `View > Line Endings > Unix` and resave with Sublime Text.

**But how to prevent this additional space to appear, regardless which text editor / platform I use?**

Comment: you could use `trim($content)` before running the regex

Comment: @treegarden oh yes, that's true `trim($matches[1])` solves the problem! (but not `trim($content)`)

Comment: oops. yes of course you're right.

Comment: @treegarden If you convert into answer, I'll accept!

Comment: That's fine. Not really worth an answer in my opinion ;) Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
preg_match("/^URL:(\S+)/", $content, $matches);
```

`\S+` matches at least one character that is not a space character. URL doesn't contain spaces, so in group 1 you have the url without spaces at the end.

If the string you want to match have spaces in the middle:

```
preg_match("/^URL:(.+?)\s*$/", $content, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain a bit? Why no more `/^URL:(.*)$/m` with `^` and `$` ?

Comment: I might use it for other fields than URL, that can have whitespaces in the middle. Is there a way to match the right thing, except the final whitespaces and except Windows/Unix linebreaks ?

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

1) you can use a non-greedy quantifier followed by an optional carriage return:

```
/^URL:(.*?)\r?$/m
```

2) you can describe more explicitly the capture group in a way that it doesn't end with a whitespace character:

```
/^URL:\h*(\S+(?:\h+\S+)*)/m
```

`\h` is a character class for horizontal whitespaces.